# WVD behind a proxy - Failure to fetch data from Azure instance Metadata service

Tags: azure, proxy, wvd

We are trying to deploy WVD in an environment where we have a proxy.

Sessionhost missing resourceId field. This is due to failure to whitelist Azure Instance Metadata service endpoint and Session host health monitoring. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-desktop/safe-url-list

From the VM, we are able to access the IPs 169.254.169.254 and 168.63.129.16 but the hostpool can't fetch these data.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The WVD team is aware of the issue and there is a fix available that will be rolled out to all customers in about 2 weeks.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information david!